# Share a state(variable) between multiple pods

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

I have two pods, which run each an instance of `ServiceA`. `ServiceA` uses a db which runs on a single separate pod.
With this setup, I'm able to deploy fluently and I'd also have a fall back service.

Now my `ServiceA` has a regular task `GatheringTask`, where it gathers information from an external service, processes them and stores it to it's db. What I'd like to prevent is that both pods that run `ServiceA` do this at the same time.

The first solution that comes to my mind is relativly easy. I create a new table in my db pod where I store the state of `GatheringTask` so each instance of `ServiceA` checks the state persisted in the db before starting its' `GatheringTask`. If on is already running, don't do it anymore. This creates quite a bit of overhead, as I have to update and read the db all the time. Also there is more code.

Now I was wondering, is there a more direct way to share a state between pods? Is there a way, I can share a env property or even map a shared memory between pods, so I do not need the detour over a third pod?
My pods are managed with kuberenetes.

Comment: You could run a `GatheringTaskService` separately, and let Kubernetes take care that exactly one instance of it is running at all time. Or maybe it could be a Kubernetes Job instead of a service if this need to be done periodically as opposed to continuously.

Comment: Have you considered etcd store ?

Answer (score 0):

A proper way of solving this task is to use a distributed lock manager, ZooKeeper for example. It's available as a docker, Kubernetes friendly image and with an appropriate recipe, for example: https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/shared-reentrant-lock.html it could provide a reliable locking mechanism.